# Scrapy truncating question marks in Response objects

Tags: python, escaping, scrapy

I have a list of URLs to a website that I am scraping. My issue is that I cannot get Scrapy to move past the first page. My best guess is that the Response object is ignoring the "?page=#". This also explains why the first page is loading as the site defaults to the first page when the page number is not specified.

Code:

```
for page in page_urls:
    Request(url=page)
    print(page)
    print(response.url)
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com/RP_Results.jsp?page=1
https://www.example.com/RP_Results.jsp
https://www.example.com/RP_Results.jsp?page=2
https://www.example.com/RP_Results.jsp
https://www.example.com/RP_Results.jsp?page=3
https://www.example.com/RP_Results.jsp
https://www.example.com/RP_Results.jsp?page=4
https://www.example.com/RP_Results.jsp
```

I have tried escaping the question mark, however, that doesn't seem to work. Also, using Response.Replace() method doesn't either. I am grateful for any and all suggestions!

Sam

Comment: What is `response`? It is very likely not being updated inside the loop. Shouldn't `Request(url=page)` be replaced with `response = Request(url=page)`?

Answer (score 1):

As @soon says, you're not storing your response anywhere.

Try this:

```
for page in page_urls:
    response = Request(url=page)
    print response.url
```

Or, the ideal way to use the response is by doing the following:

```
for page in page_urls:
    yield Request(url=page, callback=self.callback)
```

Where `self.callback` is a function that you will need to create that would handle the scraping of the response.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. A _really_ simple bug. I was under the impression Request changed the response object itself. Thanks for the help!